# How to pass data from Kohana controller to JQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, controller, kohana, kohana-3

I'm new to Kohana and I find it hard to search for some reference. I need to use the 'fullcalendar' library for my current project. I have to pass events data from my controller to my js file.

For example, I have this code in my controller:

```
/modules/calendar/classes/controller/calendar.php

$data[] = array(
    'id' => '0',
    'title' => 'Event 1',
    'start' => '2020-02-15',
    'end' => '2020-02-15'
);

echo json_encode($data);
```

I want to pass this $data to here:

```
/js/admin/fullcalendar.js

$('#prog-calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: "url-of-the-php-controller-or-template-file-I'm-not-sure"
});
```

I don't know how to link my php script to js. I thought of using AJAX but I also need a url to send the request to and I just really don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/WinterSilence/kohana-cms/blob/3.3/develop/common/classes/Controller/CMS/Ajax.php as example of backend, at frontend you send AJAX request to controller extended Controller_CMS_Ajax by route https://github.com/WinterSilence/kohana-cms/blob/be7fae88b2e1d0c9febb49c6aba8bac084842f31/bootstrap.php#L134
for example:

```js
$.post(
    'ajax/data/cities/json',
    {country: 'Russia'},
    function (response) {
        console.log(response.cities);
    }
);
```

P.s. use `route->uri()` to create url for AJAX query

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get it. How can I get data from my controller within my module?

Comment: what's exactly you don't understand?